# pgrep -f with multiple arguments

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

i try to find a specific process containing the term "someWord" and two other terms represented by $1 and $2

```
 7   regex="someWord.*$1.*$2"
 8   echo "$regex"
 9   [ `pgrep -f $regex` ] && return 1 || return 0
```

which returns

```
./test.sh foo bar
someWord.*foo bar.*
./test.sh: line 9: [: too many arguments
```

What happens to my regular expression? Doing that pgrep directly in the shell works fine.

Answer (score 10):

Good sir, perhaps this

```
[[ `pgrep -f "$regex"` ]] && return 1 || return 0
```

or this

```
[ "`pgrep -f '$regex'`" ] && return 1 || return 0
```

Answer (score 2):

First, there's no reason to wrap your `pgrep` command in anything. Just use its exit status:

```
pgrep -f "$regex" && return 1 || return 0.
```

If `pgrep` succeeds, you'll return 1; otherwise, you'll return 0. However, all you're doing is reversing the expected exit codes. What you probably want to do is simply let the `pgrep` be the last statement of your function; then the exit code of `pgrep` will be the exit code of your function.

```
something () {
   ...
   regex="someWord.*$1.*$2"
   echo "$regex"
   pgrep -f $regex
}
```

Comment: that might be true and i'll test it but isn't my regex obstructed as it displays "someWord.*foo bar.*" but should be "someWord.*foo.*bar"?

Comment: It looks like `$1` is set to "foo bar" and `$2` is not set at all. Can you add more of `test.sh` to the question?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do something in case your command returns an error:

```
cmd="pgrep -f $regex"

if ! $cmd; then
  echo "cmd failed."
else
  echo "ok."
fi
```